# Custom Column is not in the database

Tags: acumatica

I have added custom column in InventoryItem using the following:

```
public abstract class usrAlternateIDs : IBqlField { }
[PXDBString(4000, IsUnicode = true)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Alternate IDs", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
public string UsrAlternateIDs { get; set; }
```

But when I use the column for selector like this,
[image]

I checked the database table (InventoryItem) and column doesn't exist.

Comment: Added custom column by customizing Data Access.

Comment: just to confirm, when adding a field you must first publish before the field is first added to the DB.

Comment: Oh. I did that. But I don't why for some reason, it didn't work.

Comment: if there was a table entry in the project (view project xml to confirm) then it should add it on first publish. Table changes are not committed to the DB until a publish occurs (and the project is selected for publish)

Comment: Yeah. That is what my understanding too. And yeah, I had gone through XML from Edit Project XML menu item too. Maybe I might have missed it. But I checked it, the changes were in XML and I sure did publish several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added custom column in the database using Data Class editor https://help.acumatica.com/(W(3))/?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=96390b13-24a9-41cc-a3f3-3a63b2efa552.